# Laravel ErrorException & Undefined variable even though the variable is defined and has a value

Tags: laravel, undefined, laravel-blade

I am getting an Undefined Variable error even though I have passed the variable through the controller using `compact()`, and I even tried passing the variable to the blade view like so `return view('address/create', ['addresses' => $addresses]);`

Route:

```
Route::get('/addresses/create', function () {
    return view('address/create');
})->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckSuperUser::class);
```

Controller function:

```
public function create()
    {
        $addresses = Address::all();
        return view('address/create', compact('addresses'));
    }
```

View code (address/create):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <legend>Available Addresses</legend>
        @foreach($addresses as $address)
            {{ $address }}
        @endforeach
</div>
```

Error message:

```
ErrorException in 656cf590f275580a61ff680434f2a7bc0399cbdb.php line 51:
Undefined variable: addresses (View: C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\dorf\resources\views\address\create.blade.php)
```

I tried clearing the cache and views, but that didn't help at all. Restarted the server and the computer and still same error. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Your "Controller" doesn't get called.. The `function () { ... }` is your controller.

Comment: Can you add some view code

Comment: @Komal added view code. It's just a simple foreach loop.

Comment: Double check did you using the correct view path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@qasimalbaqali You are giving wrong path You have to use like this

```
Route::get('/addresses/create','ControllerName@create')->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckSuperUser::class);
```

Replace `ControllerName` with your `Controller`.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass this way

```
return view('address/create')->with('addresses', $addresses);
```

Updated

```
@foreach($addresses as $address)
   {{ $address->address }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Try like this     @foreach($addresses as $address)
            {{ $address->address }}
        @endforeach